# Align a Series of Images Together in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, alignment

I'm trying to align a series of images together in matlab.

I have a series of images which are very similar to one another. They are slightly offset in either the x or y direction. The images all have 4 crosshairs on each corner of the image to assist with alignment. I'd like to align them such that the entire series lies on top of all four crosshairs. I'd also like to crop out any differences between the files after they have been aligned.

I've been trying to get the alignment working, but I can't seem to figure it out in matlab.

Here are two sample images. [[1]](http://s19.postimage.org/hv8ae8lpv/image.jpg) [[2]](http://s19.postimage.org/8opzqyghf/image.jpg)

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: So what you want to do is create one image with all the others, using the crosses as a fix point? I can't exactly understand what you mean

Comment: That's exactly what I need! I just need to make sure that the images are all aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [image registration](http://initora.wordpress.com/article/matlab-image-processing-image-232y3pcqwxodx-19/) is what you might be looking for.

Comment: Image registration definitely works, but I'm just trying to adjust in the XY direction and possibly an angle. The resolution of these images is about 4500 pixels by 3800 pixels, so the registration process is taking for ever! Any suggestions to quickly stack the images?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
%size(img2) <= size(img1) 

img1 = 255-mean(imread('a1.png'),3); 
img2 = 255-mean(imread('a2.png'),3); 

c = normxcorr2(img2,img1); 
[y x] = find(c==max(c(:))); 
y = y-size(img2,1); 
x = x-size(img2,2); 

T = maketform('affine',[1 0 x;0 1 y; 0 0 1]'); 
img2N = imtransform(img2,T,'xdata',[1 size(img1,2)],'ydata',[1 size(img1,1)]); 
imagesc(max(img1,img2N));
axis image
```